# pip instal netifaces>=0.10.4 throws gcc compile error in suse enterprise linux 11

Tags: opensuse, sles

Hi I am trying to install few python packages and it requires the python-dev libraries. For SUSE enterprise i guess we need to download the SDK separately.

I am not sure how to download and install this. The error that I got is found in http://pastebin.com/caEJQKZu

In Ubuntu I use `apt-get install python-dev` or in yum `yum install python-devel` but there is no package in zypper like "zypper in python-dev"

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo zypper install python-devel`

Comment: I have tried it and there is no package in zypper. By googleling i fould that we have to download the the sdk iso from here "http://download.novell.com/Download?buildid=zzeQqpY9nK4~" . But i am not sure how to use this iso to install or update the packages in my sles server